# C# FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo not working on Mac OS

Tags: c#, macos

On Windows, I am using the below to get an executable file version.

```
FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo("filepath.exe").FileVersion
```

But when I use the same on Mac for a file of type unix executable , it returns null

Comment: Define: "executable file". Are you using it on an `.exe` compiled by `csc` on your Mac, or are you passing the path of a MacOS `.app` package?

Comment: Also, what makes you so sure that the "executable file" you're referring to has a Win32 PE `VERSIONINFO` resource? You do know that `VERSIONINFO` is a Windows-specific thing, right? (See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/versioninfo-resource )

Comment: Hi, can you show the full path?

Comment: Maybe it's not called `filepath.exe` on a mac?

Comment: Hey, @Dai I am just trying to get the version info for a Unix executable file. So I tried to do the same way I was using on windows. Is there another way to do that?

Comment: @raneeshchoudhary That won't work because "Unix" executables are ELF, not PE, so they don't have a `VERSIONINFO` structure. You could use a command-line tool like `file` (aka "magic-file") to get some metadata but as far as I know ELF executables do not contain version information in a machine-readable format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Reposting my comment as an answer):

#### Shortest answer:

**You can't**.

#### Short answer:

- The `FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo()` method attempts to read `VERSIONINFO` resource data from a Win32 PE binary executable image.

  - On Windows, most executables are PE images which *may or may not* contain a `VERSIONINFO` structure.
  - On macOS and Linux, *most* (but not all) executables are Mach-O and ELF images respectively, which *do not contain* a `VERSIONINFO` structure at all.

    - .NET assemblies always use the PE format, however, which means they can contain a `VERSIONINFO` structure in their resources section.
- This means that on Mac or Linux you can use `FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo()` to read only PE executable files, with the additional caveat that ([as of April 2021](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/01b7e73cd378145264a7cb7a09365b41ed42b240/src/libraries/System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo/src/System/Diagnostics/FileVersionInfo.Unix.cs)) only .NET assemblies specifically can be read, and not non-.NET assembly PE executables) can be read. Because ELF and Mach-O executables do not contain a Win32 resources section you cannot use `FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo()` on those kinds of executables.

#### Longer answer:

Windows's `*.exe` files use the "PE" executable image format: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/pe-format - this format is also used by .NET assemblies.

This format has the ability to store "resources" in a dedicated section of the file which [can optionally contain a `VERSIONINFO` record structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/versioninfo-resource) (represented [in-memory as `VS_VERSIONINFO`](http://%20https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/vs-versioninfo.)). Note that `VERSIONINFO` is a Microsoft/Win32-specific data structure.

Other operating systems use different executable image formats: Linux and most Unixes use ELF, and macOS  uses the "Mach-O" format - neither of which use `VERSIONINFO`.

Note that when using .NET Core on a non-Windows OS, the ".NET assembly" files are still
`*.exe` and `*.dll` files that use the PE executable format, but they aren't directly executed by the non-Windows OS: instead they'll have a loader program that starts the .NET runtime which then loads the .NET assemblies into it (exactly like how you run a Java program from a `*.jar` file on Windows by running `java.exe yourJar.jar`).

So because .NET Core always uses the PE format for .NET assemblies, even on non-Windows platforms, the `FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo` API is still available for the purposes of extracting version information from other .NET assemblies, but it won't work for non-PE executable image files.

Comment: The additional detail in this answer is incorrect when it states that "you can read PE version info from PE executables (including .NET assemblies)".  In fact, ONLY .net assemblies are (currently) supported, and explicitly so!  The source for `FileVersionInfo.Unix.cs` includes a comment discussing a limitation of the assembly specific implementation, with this additional statement: `If this ever becomes a problem, we can implement a full-fledged Win32 resource parser; that would also enable support for native Win32 PE files on Unix, but that should also be an extremely rare case.`

Comment: @Deltics Thank you for the correction - I assumed that they _did_ have a Win32 Resource reader library. I'll update my answer now.

Answer (score 0):

## Shortest Answer

You can't (currently).

## Short-ish Answer

As Dai explains in their answer, the version info Api's rely on underlying, native Api's which in turn expect version information to be present in a PE (portable executable) header.  Since Unix/macOS executable use a different executable header, they are not supported.

## Short Answer

Since Unix (and macOS) executables do not use the PE header format, you cannot use `FileVersionInfo` on those files since this Api currently relies on the PE header format.

Sadly, it is also not possible to use `FileVersionInfo` on all PE files when with .net Core running on a Unix/maxOS system, since it was an implementation decision to support **only** .net assemblies.  This is easier to implement as it does not require the full PE header support that `VERSIONINFO` resource-based PE headers would.

## The Full Answer

The implementation of `FileVersionInfo` on .net core does not support the executable header format used by Unix/macOS executables.  `FileVersionInfo` only supports *PE files that incoroporate CLI Metadata*.  That is, *.net assemblies*.

There are comments in the source code for `FileVersionInfo` that discuss some problems/limitations with even this level of support.  This notes that these problems should only rarely arise, but that if necessary a full PE resource parser *could* potentially be implemented and that this would then also provide support for version info in native, (non-.net) Windows executables.

The comment goes on to opine that the need for this is expected also to be extremely rare, so I don't think it will be very high on priorities.

What is frustrating is that this is not documented other than in these source comments, and attempting to use the Api on native EXE images "fails" silently, yielding an essentially empty `FileVersionInfo` object, which could be confused with any number of failures.

For completeness, here's the relevant `FileVersionInfo.Unix.cs` source and comment:

```
private FileVersionInfo(string fileName)
{
  _fileName = fileName;

  // For managed assemblies, read the file version information from the assembly's metadata.
  // This isn't quite what's done on Windows, which uses the Win32 GetFileVersionInfo to read
  // the Win32 resource information from the file, and the managed compiler uses these attributes
  // to fill in that resource information when compiling the assembly.  It's possible
  // that after compilation, someone could have modified the resource information such that it
  // no longer matches what was or wasn't in the assembly.  But that's a rare enough case
  // that this should match for all intents and purposes.  If this ever becomes a problem,
  // we can implement a full-fledged Win32 resource parser; that would also enable support
  // for native Win32 PE files on Unix, but that should also be an extremely rare case.
  if (!TryLoadManagedAssemblyMetadata())
  {
    // We could try to parse Executable and Linkable Format (ELF) files, but at present
    // for executables they don't store version information, which is typically just
    // available in the filename itself.  For now, we won't do anything special, but
    // we can add more cases here as we find need and opportunity.
  }
}
```